# Camera movement is not fluid

Tags: rendering, camera, path

fellow blender users. I have encountered a problem which messes up a lot with my renders. You see, I'm trying to render this scene as a video, and I've got 3 cameras doing that. Thing is, my renders come out as laggy and choppy, I've tried recording in 60, 30 and 24 fps, but it's always like the camera was making some weird movement instead of following the path in the smooth motion I've set up. Got any ideas on what could be the cause of these choppy renders?

[Here's the .blend if anyone wants to take a look. File so big can't even pasteall.org.](https://www.mediafire.com/file/ahj1o2rgk5uuhsf/HangerCompr.blend/file)

Comment: I'll suggest the obvious here - Cameras can do this when following paths.  Use an empty to follow each path and parent the camera to that. (Camera = child)  That will free up the cameras to pan etc as they're enjoying the ride.  I'm on an old version of Blender here so I can't d/load your file.

Comment: Suggest you use blend-exchange for Blend files. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))  Meanwhile, I've looked at your animation F-curves and the camera motion on the F-curves (being tied to the empties) is just fine, so I'm not sure what "laggy and choppy" means. Are you saying that the rendered animation is choppy, or that playback in the 3D viewport is?

Comment: (I didn't know about blend-exchange, thanks.)The rendered animation. As Edgel pointed out, it's already connected to a empty which follows a single key frame at the end located in a certain position, so the movement itself should be smooth, but when rendered it definitely isn't. I've tried multiple media programs but they all look like that. As "laggy and choppy", I see it as the camera, in the rendered animation, is jumping into the position unevenly instead of one single smooth motion.

Comment: I've tried a render and it seems to work fine, here is the video file: https://we.tl/t-D2GtNjVndm

Comment: Could it be lagging because of all the things in scene when rendered in rendered view? (i.e with all lights and textures)